# Can I call a function in a class by using a string?

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function in a class by using a string.  Example:

```
$clt = new Controller ; 
$controller = self::$controller_get[$key]."()";
$clt->$controller
```

Here I want to replace `$controller` with the name of a function.  Is that possible?

Comment: Be warned, that this approach has to be used very sparingly. It makes really hard to debug the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities

First when you try to call a function you should use the right syntax.

```
$clt->$controller();
```

but my favorite is this:

```
$className->{"variableName"};
$className->{"methodName"}();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$clt = new Controller ; 
$controller = self::$controller_get[$key];
$clt->{$controller}();
```